# R: Mapping error when using purrr's map function

Tags: r, purrr

I want to read all csv-files in a directory into R and bind them together. I use vroom to read the files and map_dfr to apply the reader to all files and bind them together. This perfectly works for a few hundred files. However, I get the following error when applying it on 3000 files.

```
mapping error: Too many open files
```

My (simplified) pipe looks as follows:

```
library(vroom)
library(dplyr)

files <- list.files(path = "some_path", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)

data_combined <- files %>%
   map_dfr(vroom)
```

The files are only approximately 100kb each, hence memory shouldn't be an issue. If someone came across this problem as well or has an idea of how to solve it, I would very much appreciate your help.

PS: The same error occurs when using fread or readr to read the files. The problem is obviously with purrr's map function.

Comment: Have you tried with couple of files insteead of the full file list i.e. `files[1:2] %>% map(vroom)` what does it output

Comment: @akrun Yes, that works perfectly. I can run it with files[1:500].

Comment: Just wanted to check if it i duee to memory.  So, you can subset only a couple of filse and test it

Comment: Yes, that works. Memory shouldn't be an issue I think.

Comment: if it works and it is only an issue when you read al the datasets, then memory would be an issue

Comment: You could try writing a function along the lines of `vroom_mod <- function(x) {vroom(x); closeAllConnections()}` and then using that in place of vroom in your map function.

Comment: You're right. That conclusion doesn't make sense. But, I can read all the 3000 files in a loop and bind them together. On my computer, I have 16GB RAM and the all the files together use 0.7 GB.

Comment: @PatrickBalada did you try `files <- fs::dir_ls(glob = "flights*tsv");vroom::vroom(files)` from here https://github.com/r-lib/vroom

Comment: @benc Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The same error occurs.

Comment: @ A. Suliman The files don't have the same number of columns. Unfortunately, I get an error using your suggestion.

Comment: Try running memory.size() and memory.limit() after the error occurs.  I've had memory issues importing multiple files when I didn't think memory should be an issue.  My workaround has been to run the imports within a 'for' statement and including a gc() to clear out memory after each file imported.